# ASP.Net Mvc Core Project unauthorized request doesn't redirect to Login page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-core, claims

I am implementing custom Authentication in an ASP.Net Core project without identity.

I have include `CookieAuthentication` just before `UseMvc`

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
{
   AuthenticationScheme = "Cookie",
   LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login/"),
   AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/Forbidden/"),
   AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
   AutomaticChallenge = true
});
```

Add Authorization for custom policy

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
   options.AddPolicy("CustomPolicy",
        policy => policy.RequireClaim("CustomClaim"));
 });
```

And at home controller I used the appropriate auth attribute

```
[Authorize(Policy = "CustomPolicy")]
public class HomeController : Controller { }
```

I would expect to be redirected to `/Account/Login/` every time I try to access `/Home/Index` but I only get `401`.

I followed these two tutorials:

- [Using Cookie Middleware without ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie)
- [Claims-Based Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims)

What I am missing?

---

Update:
This problem exists only when I am using IIS to run the app, from the exe the redirection is working properly.

Comment: Curious about this, I recently updated a production environment app to the latest NET Core version, and IIS no longer redirects to the `Account/Login` action, whereas starting the web application manually, via the executable, does redirect. I'd suggest running the exe and seeing if this is also the case for your application.

Comment: @ColinM You are right and thank you for putting that into my perspective. It's redirecting normally to login page when I run the exe. Have you find the solution? I guess the suspect  is web.config, maybe it needs the `<authentication mode="Forms">` element.

Comment: I'm going to try the authentication mode in the config when I finish work in a few hours, I'm failing to see what has changed between this and the previous release of the NET Core libraries that could have resulted in this.

Comment: I have just tried and it didn't redirect.

Comment: Have you checked the IIS Logs to see what it reports with the 401? I'm thinking it may be using IIS' expected error pages.

Comment: I updated all nuget packages and now it work in IIS too! I guess it was a bug that is fixed now.

Comment: Since that solved both of our problems, I'd suggest adding that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated all nuget packages and it solved all the problems.